# How to remove elements from a line in a text file once it is in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, split

So, I have a text file that looks exactly like this:

```
<sgkljsd>::=<sdfasfda> <sadfasf>
<lol>::=<dgs> <pdja> <l>|<np>
<or>::hello|howdy
<sdfas>::=<saf>|<sdf> <adlp>
<needd>::=huge|massive|big|tall
```

So, in this text file, line 1 and 2 are not needed so I just skip over them. However, I need the words in line 3 and in line 5. My current code splits line three at the "|" so I either get "howdy" or "::hello". So is there a way to remove elements in a line? In line 3 and in line 5, I only need the words split at the "|". I want to get rid of the items in "<  >".

My current code is below:

```
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a file name: ");
        String fileName = scan.nextLine();
        File infile = new File(fileName);
        Scanner readIt = new Scanner(infile);

        // removes first line of file
        String junkLine1 = readIt.nextLine();

        // removes second line of file
        String junkLine2 = readIt.nextLine();

        //gets random <word> from text file
        String word = readIt.nextLine();
        // breaks it into "<or>hello" and "howdy"
        String[]word1 = word.split("\\|");
        int rnd = r.nextInt(word1.length);
        String rnd_word = (word1[rndDp]);
        System.out.println(rnd_word);
```

So, what I wanted to do was randomly select the word in the array and randomly print out a greeting but I can't seem to figure out how to remove the unnecessary text. Thank you for any ideas on how to fix or approach this.

Comment: `String word = readIt.nextLine()`; `word = word.substring(word.indexOf("::")+2);` This will trim `word` to begin after the `::`.

Comment: @BethanyLouise thank you, this partially worked. However, the first word gets grabbed with the equal sign. Is there a way to remove that as well?

Comment: You could then use `if (word.contains("=")) { word = word.substring(word.indexOf("=")+1); }`

Comment: Why did you ruin this question with this edit

Comment: @bmarkham Not sure what happened. Thank you for fixing. I was in the middle of retyping everything

Answer (score 3):

You can get rid of < > replacing them all with a regex:

```
"<needd>::=huge|massive|big|tall".replaceAll("<.+?>", "");
```

which returns:

```
::=huge|massive|big|tall

"<needd>::=huge|massive|big|tall".replaceAll("<.+?>::=", "");
```

which returns:

```
huge|massive|big|tall
```

or you can also split:

```
"<needd>::=huge|massive|big|tall".split("<.+?>|:+|\\||=");
```

which will return an array of String containing:

```
{huge, massive, big, tall}
```

You can try on the combinations above here: http://www.regexpal.com/

Comment: is there a way to get it so it is just huge|massive|big|tall? Like without the ::=

Comment: replaceAll("<.+?>::=", "");

Comment: thank you! works perfectly and exactly what I needed

Comment: Hey @PeteytheProgrammer, as my answer fixed your problem, could you please accept it as the question's answer?